# How do i use a samsung galaxy phone as a camera through the USB port in Ubuntu (without giving personal info to google)?

Tags: usb, android, samsung

I have found so far that I can use something called Droidcam. But this program seems to require it to be installed on the computer and the phone. The page i was on for the linux download started with this command and was instantly followed by an error

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-uname -r
```

E: Command line option 'r' [from -r] is not understood in combination with the other options.

And when i tried to download the phone side it said i need to connect my device to google play store. 1. I can't even figure out how to do that and 2. I don't want to do that. I don't want google to be connected to my device any further than using it over a web browser.

So first of all I need help with both installs (maybe using the program after that) and i would love to be able to do it without letting google malware into my phone.

Comment: the command is supposed to be `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

Comment: Thanks, it worked but was unnecessary anyhow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*1. I can't even figure out how to do that {connect my device to google play store} and 2. I don't want to do that. I don't want google to be connected to my device any further than using it over a web browser.*

You don't need anything not already on your Samsung to connect to the Google Play Store. Just tap the Google Play icon and enter DroidCam to see:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dev47apps.droidcam&hl=en_US

The other method, 'sideloading' a downloaded APK file, is not safe, because the [developers](https://www.dev47apps.com/) don't make it downloadable. Going through a third party site to try to find the APK file for sideloading is an invitation to disaster, because who knows what they've injected into that APK. Third party repositories are **very** insecure.

Besides, Google has access to your phone if they want it, anyway; they wrote the OS!

Comment: When i go to that website (with my phone) and click install, is when i get told "This google account is not yet associated with a device. Please access the Play Store app on your device before installing apps. Learn more."  The learn more button does not provide useful information. I do not see any such app in my phone where can i get one?

Comment: It's called Google Play on standard Android phones. Maybe Samsung renamed it? Don't have a Samsung. You may need to ask where the store app is on a Samsung over on http://android.stackexchange.com/